# call cs:label instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly

What does this syntax mean?

`call cs:label`

For example I've run into such instruction:

`call cs:MessageBoxA`

why isn't it like:

`call MessageBoxA`?

---

I've found that instruction in the IDA Pro (v6.8) disassembled code of some Win `exe`file.

Here is the hex opcode of the instruction:
`2E FF 15 24 01 6C 00`

Comment: If it's literally `cs:`, then it's a segment override for a memory operand, I think. (DLL calls use a function pointer in memory).  Perhaps as padding to fill space at link time after simplifying an instruction?  IDK.  If it's a number or some other name, it's a "far" call to a different code segment, possibly to switch to 64-bit mode (I think WoW64 does this, instead of just using `sysenter` in 32-bit user-space to efficiently get into long mode in the kernel.)

Comment: What do you mean *Why is it just `call MessageBoxA`?*  You just said it's *not* that.  Did you mean why *isn't* it that?  And can you show where you've run into it?  The same thing can maybe mean different things in different x86 syntaxes.  (Especially helpful would be the corresponding machine code, so we could look up the exact instruction)

Comment: It may be a feature of your disassembler. There are tools that like to include "helpful" prefixes that do not exist in the machine code, e.g. objdump disassembles showing the default `ds` prefix on memory references via labels. It doesn't seem to do the `cs` thing, at least on my machine.

Comment: @PeterCordes I've updated my answer. Can You now help me more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a call through a function-pointer stored in memory at that symbol address.  Which is normal for a DLL call; dynamic linking updates the pointer.

But it has a CS prefix which is not normal, AFAIK.  Windows (like other mainstream x86 OSes) uses a flat memory model, the the segment base address = 0 for all of CS/DS/ES/SS.  So the CS prefix has no actual effect on the address being loaded from.

---

`2E` [really is](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html#x2E) a CS segment-override prefix, and `FF /2`<sup>2</sup> is (near) `call r/m32` (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call), so it looks like it is a near (not far) `call cs:[disp32]`.

This is a real segment-override prefix, not a reminder of the default sprinkled in by an overly helpful disassembler.  (Like some will put `mov eax, ds:label` even though there's no DS segment override prefix.)

Footnote 2: In octal, the 0x15 ModRM byte is `025`, and the `/r` field is bits [5:3], just below the 2-bit mode field at the top.  So the opcode is FF /2.

---

Weird, how was this executable created?  I didn't think compilers would do that.

Comment: As I've said - this is the IDA Pro (v6.8) disassembled code output.

Comment: So the exact instruction: `call cs:MessageBoxA` isn't valid? The `cs` prefix denoting the code segment isn't allowed?

Comment: @Daros911 The prefix is allowed, it's just rather unusual.  Also, please hold your horses.  People are not online all the time and may take some time to answer.

Comment: @fuz Ok, sorry for pressing for an answer... "The prefix is allowed" - if it's true why do i receive `error: invalid combination of opcode and operands` when try to compile: `...call  cs:_MessageBoxA@16...` using the `nasm` compiler?

Comment: @Daros911 NASM is an assembler, not a compiler.  And its syntax is slightly different.  In NASM syntax, the instruction is `call [cs:_MessageBoxA@16]`.

Comment: @fuz Ok, Yes, my mistake NASM it an assembler of course. Thx. for enlightening the syntax gotcha.

Comment: @Daros911 Watch out for differences like these.  While NASM surrounds every memory operand with parentheses, the same is not the case for MASM syntax.  Whether, say, `mov foo, eax` is a load from memory or not depends on the type of the symbol `foo`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228957/discussion-between-daros911-and-fuz).